# Client Object Model - How can I access a List using relativeServerUrl

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, client-object-model

I am using the client object model and I want to access a List using the server relative Url.
Folders can be accessed using the `web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl` but no such function exists for lists.

The available API is `web.Lists.GetByID` and `web.Lists.GetByTitle` which I can't use (The list title is different from the listname/listpath)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
public List GetListByRelativeUrl(String relativeUrl)
   {
       List existingList;

       Web web = context.Web;
       ListCollection lists = web.Lists;

       IEnumerable<List> existingLists = context.LoadQuery(
               lists.Where( list => list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl == relativeUrl)
               );
       context.ExecuteQuery();

       existingList = existingLists.FirstOrDefault();

       return existingList;
   }
```

Each list has a root folder - you can find it by using the ServerRelativeUrl property.

Answer (score 1):

You can use by this way:

```
       try
       {
            SP.ClientContext ctx = new SP.ClientContext("yoursiteurl");
            ctx.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            ctx.AuthenticationMode = SP.ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();

            IEnumerable<SP.List> newLists;
            var query = from list in ctx.Web.Lists
                        where list.DefaultViewUrl == "/Shared Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx"
                        select list;

            newLists = ctx.LoadQuery(query);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            foreach (SP.List l in newLists)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(l.Title);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

i know its old, but both solutions are not working in all cases. So its my example that work all the times

```
        public List GetListByServerRelativeUrl(ClientContext context, string relativeUrl)
    {
        List existingList;
        Web oWebsite = context.Web;
        ListCollection collList = oWebsite.Lists;
        context.Load(
            collList,
            lists => lists.Include(
                list => list.Title,
                list => list.Id,
                list => list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl));
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        existingList = collList.First(list => list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl == relativeUrl);
        return existingList;
    }
```